# Cloning Array variables in Powershell - It seems to retain a link

Tags: powershell

I've been noticing some behaviour in PowerShell that I wasn't expecting.  If I want to create a copy of an array, and change the values in the copy, the values of the original get update as well.  Why is this?  For example:

```
[array]$myVar1 = @("OldText");
$myVar2 = $myVar1;
$myVar2[0] = "newText"

Write-Output "MyVar1: $myVar1"
Write-Output "MyVar2: $myVar2"
```

I was expecting MyVar1 to be "OldText" and MyVar2 to be "NewText."  But they are now both "NewText"

Comment: [PowerShell copy an array completely](//stackoverflow.com/a/29699129)

Comment: Thanks. I need to level up my googling skills.